# boost::asio how to send string data from client and store it at server side for processing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to use boost::asio library to send raw strings from multiple clients. I need to sort the strings at server side and send it back to clients.

```
void start()
  {
    sock.async_read_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(data),
        boost::bind(&con_handler::handle_read,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    
    sock.async_write_some(
    boost::asio::buffer(data),
        boost::bind(&con_handler::handle_write, 
            shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& err,
                   size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
      std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& err,
               size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!err) {
    cout<<"server side "<<data<<endl;
    
    } else {
      std::cerr << "err (recv): " << err.message() << std::endl;
      sock.close();
    }
  }
```

However, this does not work. I get empty string on printing and on client side.

Can you please how to fix this?

Comment: Your `start` function should only call `async_read_some`. Then the `handle_read` function sorts the data *and* sends it back to the peer.

Comment: async_write_some API should not send the data back to the client? And what if multiple clients send different strings for sorting to the server side? Do I need to store a mapping of clientID and string while sending it back?

Comment: No you don't need `async_write_some`, plain `write` will work fine. But you need to do it *when* you have received some data, otherwise there's nothing to send. And assuming TCP you will have one connection (one object?) per connected client.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, I need to use sock.async_write instead of async_write_some?

Comment: No, no async writing at all! And do the writing in the `handle_read` function when you actually have received some data to write.

Comment: OK thanks. I am just starting with boost::asio, so not much acquainted with the library. I will try your suggestion. My server class is holding a object of tcp:acceptor class and constructor calls acceptor_.async_accept API which will listen for connections? will this work for multiple clients?

Comment: I cannot recommend using `read_some` here. That's a bad idea 99% of the time, since packet distribution on the wire cannot be relied on.

Comment: Ok. I actually want to design a stream service where server side sorts the incoming strings and stores in some file and also sends it back to client. Can you recommend a good approach. The above code doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of relevant code missing, but

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Tells me that `data` is probably `array<char, N>` or `std::vector<char>`.

> It cannot be `std::string` because you'd have needed `asio::dynamic_buffer(data)` instead of `asio::buffer(data)`.

Now

- if `array<char, N>` is used, then `end()` iterator will always be the end of the buffer, regardless of how many bytes were received. That's not what you want because the buffer will contain trailing garbage - and/or likely NUL characters which will mess up your output.
- if `vector<char>` is used, then the classical mistake is that its size is zero (it's `empty()`) so `buffer(data)` actually is a zero-byte buffer and nothing ever gets received, the sort does nothing and nothing gets sent.

Regardless, the `sort` call doesn't do what you describe:

> *I am trying to use boost::asio library to send raw strings from multiple clients. I need to sort the strings at server side and send it back to clients.*

This suggests that you sort separate "strings" (maybe separate lines of text?). You code sorts **characters** in a string. Not the same thing.

Here's a rough sketch of a solution where the server accumulates `_strings` (line-wise) from several clients, and writes the sorted collection back to each when their connection ends:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a0de27352a8d0a5)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <deque>

namespace net = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using net::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

using Executor = net::io_context::executor_type;
using Acceptor = net::basic_socket_acceptor<tcp, Executor>;
using Socket   = net::basic_stream_socket<tcp, Executor>;

struct Server {
    Acceptor _acc;
    Server(Executor ex) : _acc(ex, {{}, 7878}) {
        _acc.listen();
        do_accept();
    }

    void addString(std::string line) {
        std::cerr << "addString: " << std::quoted(line) << std::endl;
        line += '\n';
        _strings.push_back(std::move(line));
    }

    auto getStrings() const { return _strings; }

  private:
    void do_accept()
    {
        _acc.async_accept([this](error_code ec, Socket&& s) {
            std::cerr << "do_accept: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            if (!ec.failed()) {
                std::cerr << "Accepted " << s.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
                std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s), *this)->start();

                do_accept();
            }
        });
    }

    struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
        Session(Socket&& s, Server& server)
            : _socket(std::move(s))
            , _server(server)
        {
        }

        void start() {
            read_loop();
        }

      private:
        void read_loop()
        {
            async_read_until(_socket, _buf, "\n",
                 [self = this->shared_from_this(),
                  this](error_code ec, size_t bytes) {
                     std::cerr << "read_loop: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                     if (!ec || ec == net::error::eof) {
                         std::istream is(&_buf);
                         std::string  line;
                         if (getline(is, line)) {
                             _server.addString(std::move(line));
                         }
                     }

                     if (ec == net::error ::eof) {
                         _reply = _server.getStrings();
                         std::sort(_reply.begin(), _reply.end());
                         write_loop();
                     }

                     if (!ec) {
                         read_loop();
                     }
                 });
        }

        void write_loop() {
            if (_reply.empty())
                return;

            async_write(
                _socket, net::buffer(_reply.front()),
                [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t) {
                    std::cerr << "write_loop: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    if (!ec) {
                        _reply.pop_front();
                        write_loop();
                    }
                });
        }

        Socket                  _socket;
        net::streambuf          _buf;
        Server&                 _server;
        std::deque<std::string> _reply;
    };

    std::deque<std::string> _strings;
};

int main() {
    net::io_context io;

    Server s(io.get_executor());

    io.run_for(10s);
}
```

With the sample clients:

```
for a in foo 'bar\nqux' xyz abc
do printf "=== %s\n" "$a"
    echo -e "$a" | netcat -N 127.0.0.1 7878
done
```

Prints

```
do_accept: Success
Accepted 127.0.0.1:34582
read_loop: End of file
addString: "foo"
write_loop: Success
do_accept: Success
Accepted 127.0.0.1:34584
read_loop: Success
addString: "bar"
read_loop: End of file
addString: "qux"
write_loop: Success
write_loop: Success
write_loop: Success
do_accept: Success
Accepted 127.0.0.1:34586
read_loop: End of file
addString: "xyz"
write_loop: Success
write_loop: Success
write_loop: Success
write_loop: Success
do_accept: Success
Accepted 127.0.0.1:34588
read_loop: End of file
addString: "abc"
write_loop: Success
write_loop: Success
write_loop: Success
write_loop: Success
write_loop: Success
```

And the clients output:

```
=== foo
foo
=== bar\nqux
bar
foo
qux
=== xyz
bar
foo
qux
xyz
=== abc
abc
bar
foo
qux
xyz
```

Comment: Thank You so much your suggestion. I am going to try this out. Meanwhile, I need to send the sorted string back to the client from which it has received the original string.

Comment: I am using boost 1.64  and I suppose boost::asio::io_context::executor_type is not available in that release. Can you suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Upgrade boost :) (seriously, 1.64 is OLD and had lots of small interface differences. Here's 1.64 compatible code, but I really suggest you upgrade: https://godbolt.org/z/cWscbaoxo

Comment: Thank You so much. Appreciate your time and help. Btw, the company I work for uses Boost 1.64 with old gcc version 4.4.4. So, now its seems this version of gcc does not support lambda functions :(. So, do I need to replace lambda calls with boost::bind??

Comment: You need to upgrade your employer (or the compiler version, whichever is easier). But seriously, yes: you have to replace all the modern C++ with crutches. Not fun: https://godbolt.org/z/c6v4ed1d8